# Importing a whole python hierarchy dynamically

Tags: python, import, inspect, imp

I have written my own python code, organized in dirs and sub dirs hierarchy

I'm trying to use this code (package/module, I'm not sure about the terminology) in a few projects.

The issue is that the code path differes between the projects.

How can I import the whole dirs, subdirs and sub files hierarchy in each project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide some example?

Comment: In linux you can add it to the pythonpath, you add a line in the bash_profile: export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<dir>

Comment: please show your hierarchy of dirs.

Answer (score 0):

try this with your code before the import statements

```
from sys import path
path += [<path>] # Here You specify the path of the library package
```